# Creating custom topology rules in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology

I am attempting to create Topology Rules in my project, because the existing topology rules  in ArcGIS Pro are not enough for my requirements.

Can I create custom topology rules in ArcGis Pro?